# Css not getting applied dynamically using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
function printPopupPage(elem)
{
    var skinUrl = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN); ?>';
    var path = skinUrl+"frontend/enterprise/woodstream/css/styles.css";
    var pathlocal = skinUrl+"frontend/enterprise/terro/css/local.css";
    var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=751');
    printWindow.document.write('<html>');
    printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="'+path+'" />');
    printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="'+pathlocal+'" />');
    printWindow.document.write('<div class="print">');
    printWindow.document.write(jQuery(elem).html());
    printWindow.document.write('</div>');
    printWindow.document.write('</html>');
    //printWindow.location.reload();
    printWindow.show();
    //printWindow.print();
    if (navigator.appName != 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        printWindow.close();
    }
    else
    {
        window.setTimeout(function() {printWindow.close()}, 3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Some comment on what exactly is wrong would be nice. Links should be in <header> while divs should be in <body>. And this is really weird way of attaching style sheets...

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to create elements and append them dynamically to the `<head>` I suggest to use `document.createElement()` in JavaScript.

```
var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=751'),
    skinUrl = '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN); ?>',
    doc = printWindow.document,
    woodstream = doc.createElement('script');

woodstream.type = 'text/css';
woodstream.media = 'all';
woodstream.href = skinUrl + 'frontend/enterprise/woodstream/css/styles.css';
(doc.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || doc.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(woodstream);
// and so on
```